# How to change value of

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case

I have a table that looks like this:

```
date|type|number
--------------------
28-jun-21,dog,23
28-jun-21,cat,24
28-jun-21,lion,23
```

I want to do a select statement that changes the dog value to `hyena`. So, it'd look like this:

```
date|type|number
--------------------
28-jun-21,hyena,23
28-jun-21,cat,24
28-jun-21,lion,23
```

Here is my code so far:

```
select date, case when type='dog' then type='hyena', number
from table1;
```

I am new to SQL and Oracle so any ideas or suggestions as to how to accomplish this would help.

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
select date,
       case when type = 'dog' then 'hyena'
            else type
       end as type,
       number
from table1
```

Though, note that `date` and `number` can't be used as column names, they are reserved for datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

All three of the identifiers you've chosen - `"type"`, `"date"`, and `"number"` - are reserved words in Oracle, and thus they must be quoted to be used as field names in a table. This also means they must be quoted every time they're used in an SQL statement, and so your SELECT statement should be something like:

```
SELECT "date",
       CASE "type"
         WHEN 'dog' THEN 'hyena'
         ELSE "type"
       END AS "type",
       "number"
  FROM TABLE1
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76e3502a29444cbbbecc70be6f0e2a95)